# Как передать значение php-переменной в javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Есть гостевая книга. Textarea и button. На php сделал, все работает. Но захотелось добавить ajax ,чтобы страница не перезагружалась.

Каким образом можно сообщить javascript'у id пользователя?

---

Поправлюсь. Как сделать это же, если сам javascript в подключаемом файле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делайте запрос так, а в php уже разбирайтесь в сессии, какой id у пользователя.

Comment: Точно! А я все думал, как именно передать. Все гораздо проще)

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
Ajax:
<?php
echo $userId;
?>
```

2.

```
Ahah:
<?php
echo "var userid = ".$userId;
?>
```

Проще всего. JSONы, XMLи и прочие уже сложнее =)